# Difference between sizeof(*ptr) and sizeof(struct)

Tags: c, sizeof

I tried the following program

```
struct temp{
   int ab;
   int cd;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   struct temp *ptr1;
   printf("Sizeof(struct temp)= %d\n", sizeof(struct temp));
   printf("Sizeof(*ptr1)= %d\n", sizeof(*ptr1));
   return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Sizeof(struct temp)= 8
Sizeof(*ptr1)= 8
```

In Linux I have observed at many places the usage of `sizeof(*pointer)`. If both are same why is `sizeof(*pointer)` used ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I generally prefer `sizeof(*ptr)` because if you later go back and change your code such that `ptr` now has a different type, you don't have to update the `sizeof`.  In practice, you could change the type of `ptr` without realizing that a few lines further down, you're taking the structure's size.  If you're not specifying the type redundantly, there's less chance you'll screw it up if you need to change it later.

In this sense it's one of those "code for maintainability" or "code defensively" kind of things.

Others may have their subjective reasons.  It's often fewer characters to type.  :-)

Comment: I would also view this as a good example of using the compiler's type system to your benefit, since there is no way you can overrun a `*ptr` without an explicit cast of pointer types by the caller or a warning being issued. 

I also like `_Static_assert(sizeof(*ptr)==sizeof(thetype_t),"You didn't finish modifying the code.");` for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` works in one of two ways: 1) with a type, 2) with an expression. The latter case is identical to calling `sizeof` on the type of the expression.

So you can write this:

```
int a;

char p[sizeof(int)];
char q[sizeof a];
```

Both mean the same thing.

The utility of the expression version for declaring a pointer to dynamic memory is that you only need to spell out the type once:

```
complex_type * pc = malloc(sizeof(*pc) * 100); // room for 100 elements
```

If you later choose to change the type of `*pc`, you only have to change the code in one single place.